# C# Open Popup in WebBrowser With ScriptErrorsSuppressed Property False

Tags: c#, popup, webbrowser-control

I followed Microsoft Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting?view=netframework-4.8)

```
private void frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{   
   webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;  
   webBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop = true;  
   webBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = true;  
   webBrowser.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = true;  
   webBrowser.Navigate(URL_LOGON); 
}
```

But my popup only open with webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false, showing JavaScript confirmation messages.

Comment: Hi there, can you show some code?

Comment: private void frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;
     webBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop = true;
     webBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = true;
     webBrowser.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = true;
     webBrowser.Navigate(URL_LOGON);
 }

Comment: pff. update your question please; its not fun to read your code in a comment

Comment: I cannot. sorry.

Comment: maybe privilege? I did it for you.